# Is it possible to use jinja values in javascript/jquery functions

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

looking at the google web eng example;

```
{% for greeting in greetings %}
  {% if greeting.author %}
    <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
  {% else %}
    An anonymous person wrote:
  {% endif %}
  <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

so what i want is: when this iterates, i need to somehow check greeting.author agains some variable that exists in javascript, and then do some other stuff.
is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{% for greeting in greetings %}
  {% if greeting.author %}
    <b>{{ greeting.author }}</b> wrote:
  {% else %}
    An anonymous person wrote:
  {% endif %}
  <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var greeting_author = "{{ greeting.author }}";
     if(greeting_author === someVariable){
        // do other stuff here
     }
  </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, you can just print the variable as js. Keep the type in mind (for example put `""` around them for strings).

Comment: i see. so it has to be inside the html. in other words we can't write a loop in a javascript function and iterate through greetings.